# How sum in MongoDB nested document when the KEY is uncertain ？

Tags: mongodb

First of all the status codes("200","404" or other) and time("1000","2000"..) are uncertain,

I want to calculate the number(5, 6 ...) for each status codes.

For example: {"200" : 11}, {"404" :11}   or  {"total" : 22}

Data Structure :

```
"_id"    : "xxxxx"
"domain" : "www.test.com"
"status" : [ 
               {"200" : [ {"1000" : 5}, {"2000": 6} ...]},
               {"404" : [ {"1000" : 5}, {"2000": 6} ...]}
                ....
           ]
```

Any fantastic methods in MongoDB ? 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use data, like dates, as keys. Data belongs in values. The HTTP status codes are enumerated - you know all the possibilities - so you can use those as keys if you want to. From the look of the documents, you are storing information about requests to a page in a page document with the requests in an array. It's not a great idea to have an unbounded, constantly growing array in a document. I'd suggest refactoring the data to be request documents with the address denormalized into each:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "status" : 404,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-10-30T18:23:09.471Z"),
    "domain" : "www.test.com"
}
```

and then you can get the total number of 404 requests to test.com with the aggregation

```
db.requests.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "domain" : "www.test.com" } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$status", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
])
```

Index on `domain` to make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the aggregation framework to pull something like that.

Check this:
db.errors.aggregate([{$unwind: "$status"}, {$group: {_id: "$status", total:{$sum:1}}}])

It will render a result like this:
...
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "500" : [ 
                    {
                        "1000" : 5
                    }, 
                    {
                        "2000" : 6
                    }
                ]
            },
            "total" : 1
        },
...

The "total" field has the count that you're looking for.

Hope this helps.

Regards!